# How do I sort by one field, and subsort by another field, in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have to solve SQL problem.

I want to sort the following order.

```
VochurNo1   

      Code0001     
      Code0002 
      Code0003

VochurNo2
     Code0005
VochurNo3
     Code0004
     Code0006
```

First sort is VochurNo and then second sort is CodeNoOrder within VochurNo..
how to sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're wanting Order By.

```
order by VochurNo , CodeNoOrder
```